# Login Facebook - Xamarin

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin, xamarin.android, facebook-login

I'm developing an app where the user will use to login to access facebook.
Is returning an error and researched and apparently would be key problem, but the key is in the Manifest.

The Following is an excerpt Manifest

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/stg_app_nome" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
          android:label="@string/stg_app_nome" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="xxxxxxx"/>
</application>
```

In Layout

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
android:id="@+id/login_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

I have then onCreate

```
base.OnCreate (bundle);
FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize (ApplicationContext);
callbackManager = CallbackManagerFactory.Create();
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Login);
loginButton = (LoginButton) FindViewById(Resource.Id.login_button);
loginButton.RegisterCallback (callbackManager, cCallbackFacebook);
```

The class CCallback  I've seen in an example and I am using

```
public class CCallback : Java.Lang.Object, IFacebookCallback {
    public void OnCancel() {
        Android.Util.Log.Warn("LIVE MATCH","Canceled");
    }

    public void OnError(FacebookException error) {
        Android.Util.Log.Error("LIVE MATCH", error.Message);
    }

    public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result) {
        Android.Util.Log.Info("LIVE MATCH", "Success");
    }
}
```

The error that is returned

> java.lang.NullPointerException at at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey
>   (ConcurrentHashMap.java:911) at at
>   com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings (Utility.java:822) at
>   at com.facebook.login.widget .LoginButton $ 1.run
>   (LoginButton.java:489) at at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
>   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) at at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor $ Worker.run
>   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) at at java.lang.Thread.run
>   (Thread.java:841)

Comment: What is your error? (stack trace?)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to report the error.
Edit the question by placing the error in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the login button in your XML resource ?

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/splash_welcome_loginbtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/continueFB"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:minHeight="44dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/splash_welcome_readybtn"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="13dp" />
```

Did you use these assemblies ?

```
using Xamarin.Facebook;
using Xamarin.Facebook.Login;
```

...

```
        ICallbackManager callbackManager;
        callbackManager = CallbackManagerFactory.Create ();
```

Your implementation seems wird to me...

Comment: Yes I declared the the XML button.
I am using assemblies 
using Xamarin.Facebook;
At the beginning of onCreate implement base.OnCreate (bundle); FacebookSdk.Sdk Initialize (ApplicationContext); callbackManager CallbackManagerFactory.Create = (); SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Login);

Answer (score -1):

Please try this. If it does not work, uncomment commented code and try once.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    /*
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.fbtest", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }*/
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
     // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new     FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
             userId = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();
             token = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });    
}
```

Comment: does not recognize FacebookCallback

Comment: please add LoginButton loginButton;
 CallbackManager callbackManager;
  String userId;
  String token ;

Comment: Please note this question is about Xamarin and your code snippet is in Java. It's not very helpful.